# Configuring new Firebase events in GTM?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I have connected Firebase with my iOS app and connected GTM.

Currently I am sending firebase event fires from the client-side (iOS app) when I want to track a custom event, such as a custom click or action.

My question is there anyway in GTM to configure the tracking of a specific custom event (click or action) without having to code in the firebase event fire function in the client-side.

For example, if I decide to track another event, I do not want to go into my iOS app and add the code and re-deploy it. That means users have to update the app to that my new tracking event will be tracked.

Is there any way similar to how GTM scraps the DOM on websites to find if a particular element is clicked or scroll action is done, so that a event and tag is trigger in GTM.

Can I install my Firebase and GTM on my iOS app and only use GTM to configure all event tracking? Or do I always need to have the Firebase Event Fire calls in my iOS App to fire events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several [events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en) that are automatically tracked (without any coding) by the Firebase SDK. For these events, you do not need to do anything as a developer except add the Firebase SDK to your project.

For all other events (like menu clicks) you will always need to explicitly send these events by coding them. There is no equivalent, in the app world, to click listeners are there is in Web GTM.

However, this does not mean that you necessarily have to release a new app version every time you want to track a new event. The best practice here is to **be generous** with your event tracking when you're first developing the app. Pass as many events as you can to Firebase in your initial app version. Then, down the line, you can always decide to include/exclude certain events depending on your needs.

Comment: So does that mean I have to update my container json file in the app when my GTM changes? or if I make changes in GTM, the container json file does not need to change? For example, in GA cd1 becomes cd3 and I update that in GTM, do I need to update the container json?

Comment: No, the JSON container file has another purpose. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837999/do-we-need-to-update-containers-json-file-in-android-side-everytime-we-change-i) for an explanation of what the JSON container file does.

Comment: Thanks. I see, its only the default container stuff. But I am experiecing a problem where I did a publish to my GTM container. But when I run the app from xCode, it is still using the old version of a published GTM, not the currently published version. So do I need to clean out anything or scrap for the new GTM version with any calls?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Eventually the app will load the **new** container from the network. However this can take some time. The default refresh time is 12 hours. So, **at most** it can take up to 12 hours (assuming there is an active network connection) for the newest container to be loaded. If you want to **force** a container refresh, you can use the `refresh()` method described [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/#refresh).

Comment: Thanks for that. Thats the Android version, but I will be looking for the swift documentation on that. Thanks.

Comment: Swift documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v3/swift).
Please mark the answer as correct if I've answered your question.